# Supremum of conditional expectations

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Let $X_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real valued random variables defined on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ with filtration $F_{n}\subseteq F$ and the $X_{n}$ being not adapted. If we have: $$\mathbb{E}(\underset{n}{\sup} |X_{n}|)<\infty$$
Does it hold true that: $$\mathbb{E}(\underset{n}{\sup} (\mathbb{E}(X_{n}|F_{n})))<\infty$$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I know that: $$\underset{n}{\lim}\mathbb{E}(\sup X_{m}|F_{n})=\mathbb{E}(\sup X_{m}|F_{\infty})$$ a.s. by a martingale convergence theorem and in $L^{1}$. For each member of the convergent sequence i have trivially: $$\mathbb{E}(X_{n}|F_{n})\leq \mathbb{E}(\sup X_{m}|F_{n})$$. With uniform convergence in hands i could have some estimations. Or even the above for the limes superior.

Comment: If i have $X_{1},X_{2}$ being iid. for example and i take $F_{1}=\sigma(X_{2}), F_{2}=\sigma(X_{1},X_{2})$ then i have $\mathbb{E}(X_{1}|F_{1})=\mathbb{E}(X_{1})$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_{2}|F_{2})=X_{2}$. So the one supremum might be bigger than the other one wether $X_{1}\geq \mathbb{E}(X_{1})$ or not. The conditional expectations do less vary than the original unconditional versions and they have less greater values but also less smaller values. But do they behave well enough?

Answer (score 0):

If I further assume $b:=\mathbb{E}((\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} X_{i})^{2})<\infty$ then i have by an application of Doobs Maximal Inequality:
$$\mathbb{E}(\underset{k\leq n}{\max}\mathbb{E}(X_{k}|F_{k}))\leq \mathbb{E}(\underset{k\leq n}{\max}\mathbb{E}(\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} X_{i}|F_{k}))\leq \mathbb{E}(\underset{k\leq n}{\max}|\mathbb{E}(\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} X_{i}|F_{k})|)\leq 1 + \mathbb{E}((\underset{k\leq n}{\max}|\mathbb{E}(\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} X_{i}|F_{k})|)^{2})\overset{\text{DoobsMaximalIneq.}}{\leq}1 + 4 
\mathbb{E}((\mathbb{E}(\sup X_{i}|F_{n}))^{2})\overset{\text{JensenIneqCond.}}{\leq}1 + 4 
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}((\sup X_{i})^{2}|F_{n}))= 1 + 4 \mathbb{E}((\sup X_{i})^{2})= 1 + 4b <\infty$$
So $\mathbb{E}(\underset{k\leq n}{\max}\mathbb{E}(X_{k}|F_{k}))$ is bounded and converges by monotone convergence to $\mathbb{E}(\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} \mathbb{E}(X_{i}|F_{i}))$ which is also bounded by 1+4b cause it holds true for every member of the sequence.